# meta_query where the meta value is not the post title

Tags: wp-query, query, meta-query

I have a meta_query where I am getting children of a page, I am trying to only get children where the meta key is not the same as the posts title

```
$args = array(
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'parent'         => $post->ID,
  'post_type'      => 'post_type',
  'post_status'    => 'publish',
  'sort_column'    => 'menu_order',
  'meta_query'     => array(
    array(
      'key'     => 'my_acf_key',
      'value'   => [how do I add the post title here]
      'compare' => '!=',
    )
  )
  $result = new WP_Query($args);
```

I am willing to do a custom query, but I was hoping there would be a way to do this with the WP_Query function (that and I have no idea how to even think about building the custom query with the joins necessary to get both tables searched)

I would just get them all and filter after the result  is fetched, but I am querying a few thousand fields so the time delay is noticeable

Comment: Unfortunately this simply isn't possible via WP_Query. It's just not smart enough under the hood.

Comment: Something like `get_the_title(wp_get_post_parent_id($post->ID))`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that works (thanks Steve), hopefully somebody will find this useful in the future

```
$sql = "SELECT p.ID FROM wp_posts AS p
  WHERE post_parent = $post->ID
  AND post_type = 'post_type'
  AND ID IN (
   SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta AS pm
     WHERE pm.meta_key = 'my_acf_key'
     AND pm.meta_value = p.post_title
);";

$idList = $wpdb->get_col( $sql );
```